# BroadcastReceiver will received "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" when app start

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

"android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE", I think this intent action will broadcast when WiFi Off/Disconnect/Connect.

When I start my apps, receiver will received the "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" this action but my device still connected the WiFi. WiFi state didn't change.

And I use adb logcat filiter "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE", I didn't see any system broadcast but start my apps will show received.

I've test on Android 5.1/6.0/7.0

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WifiBroadcastReceiver wifiBroadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
        filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(wifiBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }
}

class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG = "WifiBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {
        //When Start App, it always received "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" and "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE".
        if ("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE".equals(paramIntent.getAction())) {
            Log.e(TAG, paramIntent.getAction());
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = paramIntent.getParcelableExtra("wifiInfo");
            //It will print the current connected SSID
            Log.e(TAG, wifiInfo.getSSID());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what error you are getting

Comment: I think I shouldn't received "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" when my app start